# prove $F[x]/g(x)$ is not an integral domain

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

If $g(x)$ is reducible in $F[x]$ then $F[x]/g(x)$ is not an integral domain.

I know that an integral domain must have no zero divisors but Im I little confused on how this works with polynomials. So far Im thinking: If $g(x)$ is reducible then

$$g(x)=f(x)h(x)$$

for some $f, g \in F[x]$. I can't see how this leads $F[x]/g(x)$ having a $a(x),b(x)$ such that $a(x)b(x)=0$

I've seen some other answers that use this notation: $\langle g(x)\rangle$ but Im not too sure what that means. I think maybe the congruence class of $g(x)$?

Comment: $\langle g(x)\rangle$ means the ideal generated by $g(x)$, also written $(g(x))$.

Comment: @rschwieb yes sorry that was a mistake. For a couple minutes I thought $F[x]/g(x)$ meant, the set of all polynomials minus $g(x)$ but it definitely does not mean this. I will delete the question shortly. Very sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce modulo $\;\langle g(x)\rangle\;$ :

$$(f+\langle g\rangle)+(h+\langle g\rangle):=fh+\langle g\rangle=g+\langle g\rangle =\overline 0$$

All you need now is to convince yourself that $\;f+\langle g\rangle\,,\,\,h+\langle g\rangle\neq\overline 0\;$